# Script runs from terminal, but not cron. What edits to this script do I need to make?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a script used for zipping a database and site files, then dumps the output into a backup folder on the server. The script runs fine from the command line, but it will not work through cron.

After much research, I am thinking that cron cannot run it in its current form because it runs in a different environment.

Here is the script, saved as `file_name.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")
FILE="website.com.$NOW.tar"
BACKUP_DIR="/backupfolder"
WWW_DIR="/var/www/website/"
DB_USER="dbuser"
DB_PASS="dbpw"
DB_NAME="dbname"
DB_FILE="website.com.$NOW.sql"

WWW_TRANSFORM='s,^var/www/website,www,'
DB_TRANSFORM='s,^backupfolder,database,'

tar -cvf $BACKUP_DIR/$FILE --transform $WWW_TRANSFORM $WWW_DIR
mysqldump -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME > $BACKUP_DIR/$DB_FILE

tar --append --file=$BACKUP_DIR/$FILE --transform $DB_TRANSFORM $BACKUP_DIR/$DB_FILE
rm $BACKUP_DIR/$DB_FILE
gzip -9 $BACKUP_DIR/$FILE
```

I currently have the script stored in `/usr/local/scripts/`

1. Is there something wrong with the above code that does not allow it to run through cron?
2. Which crontab should it go in? `crontab -e` from terminal, or `/etc/crontab`? They are two different files.

Comment: I removed the `python` tag as this has no (obvious) connection to Python..

Comment: @Eric, Show us your cron entry

Comment: I have tried: `1 1 * * * /usr/local/scripts/backup-file_name.sh` and `1 1 * * * bash /usr/local/scripts/backup-file_name.sh`. I have also tried putting a copy of the script in `/etc/cron.hourly` with no luck.

Comment: what does the /var/log/cron say?

Comment: The format in your comment is suitable for `crontab -e` but not for putting in `/etc`. Either way, you (or `root`) should be receiving email if there was a problem. Could it be that the script is running, but taking a long time?

Comment: Is the file called `backup-file_name.sh` or just `file_name.sh`? Do you not want it to have a descriptive name?

Comment: @frankc - There is no `/var/log/cron` file or directory. @tripleee - The total output is only about 70 megs, and it runs pretty quickly when I do it manually. The file name does have a desciptive name, but I changed it to something generic for posting here. I realize now I used two different names above, but they do match in crontab -e.

Comment: @Eric, the way to mark a question as solved is to provide your own answer and mark that as accepted. (not sure if you need a certain rep for that).

Comment: @glennjackman - I tried, but my rep is not high enough.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I fixed it. Not sure what the problem was, but this worked for me.

I originally had the scripts located in `/usr/local/scripts/`

I created a new directory here - `/scripts/` and moved the scripts there. The new `crontab -e` command looked like this:

`1 1 * * * bash /scripts/file_name.sh`

Works perfectly. Again, I am not sure what the issue was before, but it works now.

Comment: Note this looks for a script in /scripts/file_name.sh, not in /usr/local/scripts/file_name.sh. If script was not ran from /usr/local/..., that was most probably some permission or SELinux issue.

Answer (score 0):

Several things come to mind: first, one of the most common problems with cron jobs is that generally crond runs things with a very minimal PATH (usually just /usr/bin:/bin), so if the script uses any commands from some other binaries directory, it'll fail. Where is `mysqldump` on your system (run `which mysqldump` if you aren't sure)? If this is the problem, adding `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` (or whatever's appropriate in your case) at the beginning of your script should fix it. Alternately, you can set PATH in the crontab file (put this line *before* the entry that runs your script).

If that's not the problem, my next step would be to capture the script's output, with something like:

```
1 1 * * * /usr/local/scripts/file_name.sh >/tmp/file_name.log 2>&1
```

... and see if the output is informative. BTW, as @tripleee mentioned, the format of your cron entry is suitable for the files `crontab -e` edits, but not for /etc/crontab. The /etc version has an additional field specifying which user to run the job as, e.g.

```
1 1 * * * eric /usr/local/scripts/file_name.sh >/tmp/file_name.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to always use crontab -e (the resultant files are usually in /var/spool/cron/) and this works on every unix and linux platform I ever worked on.

Other common issues with cron execution are missing environment variables.  Any environment variables set in .bash_profile (or .profile if you use korn shell) will not necessarily be present in the cron environment.  This can be overcome by including them in your script.

As Gordon said, paths are another suspect.  You can always full path you executables in your script (eg /bin/mysqldump).  Some of the more cynical of us do this anyway to make sure we are executing what we intended as apposed to some other file of the same name in the current path.

I can only guess at your specific problem since you fixed it by creating /scripts, that perhaps the permissions on /usr/local/scripts directory did not allow execution by the cron user?

Answer (score -1):

I have had to remove the extension (.sh) for cron to run in some instances.

Comment: That is very unlikely that would help. I guess other condition changed.